# Как закрыть VideoCapture в EmguCV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

В первый раз все считывается нормально. Во второй уже программа закрывается. На `m1.Read(m1)`. Кажется я неправильно его выгружаю из памяти.

```
capture = new Emgu.CV.VideoCapture(fileName);

   m1 = new Mat();
   m1.Read(m1);

   capture.Pause();
   capture.Dispose();
```

Comment: Вы [документацию](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0-r16.12/document/html/5d3e2a38-d2a8-494c-37e0-387d610a87ab.htm) читали?

Comment: @Yami да читал. В чем проблема?

Comment: Вы после захвата кадра уничтожаете объект и заново создаете его для каждого кадра? Для остановки есть метод `Stop`.

Comment: [VideoCapture.Stop](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0-r16.12/document/html/2e644e9a-ee1a-1f91-9a0d-8123310d6110.htm) пробовали?

Comment: @tym32167: Думаю ТС не пробовал, но пишет что читал документацию.

Comment: @Yami ну, значит попробует :)